# Formulação de lógica para resolução de problema

Tags: php, mysql

tenho duas tabelas, a tabela A com o id e as tarefas (descrição), e uma outra tabela B com a fk da tarefa, quantidade, fk funcionario. Além de outras colunas que não vem ao caso.

Na minha tabela no html (table), mostro todos as tarefas já no thead, e nos resultados pego as quantidades respectivas de cada tarefa.

O problema é que uma loja pode cadastrar 5 tarefas, e cadastrar atividades para seus funcionarios, porém, depois de um tempo, ela pode cadastrar mais uma tarefa, só que qd isso ocorre, minha visualização da tabela no html quebra. Pois na minha tabela B não existe dados dessa nova tarefa.

Alguém teria alguma sugestão de como solucionar esse problema?

Parte da query de busca das quantidades de tarefas:

```js
//tabela A, checo todas as tarefas cadastradas
  $consulta2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_tarefa FROM tarefa WHERE id_loja=:id");
   $consulta2->bindParam(':id', $id_loja, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    
           if($consulta2->execute()){

               if($consulta2->rowCount() > 0){

                 while($dados_cons2 = $consulta2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                            

                            $id_tarefa2=$dados_cons2->id_tarefa;
                       

  //essa seria minha tabela B, checo todas as atividades, que possuem as quantidades da tarefas
  $dados3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM atividades_diarias as ativ where ativ.id_ativ=:id_ativ and ativ.id_loja=:id_loja and ativ.tipo_atividade=:tipo and ativ.id_tarefa=:id_taf");

                    $dados3->bindParam(':id_ativ',$id_ativ, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $dados3->bindParam(':id_loja',$id_loja, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $dados3->bindParam(':tipo',$tipo_atividade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $dados3->bindParam(':id_taf',$id_tarefa2, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                    $dados3->execute();

                         while($table3 = $dados3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                                       
                 $qtd_tarefa = $table3->qtd_tarefa;

                    //só que as tarefas novas n tem dados antigos na minha tabela B, ele é inexistente, aí quebra a tabela
                     if($qtd_tarefa!=null){ //usei null mas n funcionou
                                    echo'<td>'.$qtd_tarefa.'</td>';
                              }else{
                                     $vazio="";
                                             echo'<td>'.$vazio.'</td>';
                                                }

                                                   }
```

Minha tabela no HTMl (exemplificação)

Data....Nome funcionario...tarefa1....tarefa2...NOVATAREFA.....horario entrada
1/6/18.........Isadora...............2................3..............08:00

Resultado que preciso:
Data....Nome funcionario...tarefa1....tarefa2...NOVATAREFA.....horario entrada
1/6/18.........Isadora..............2.............3.....................VAZIO.................08:00

Perceba que a nova tarefa cadastrada pega o valor da próxima coluna, qd deveria colocar vazio, já que não existe dados histórico sobre ela.

Alguém sabe como posso verificar p saber se minha tarefa existe na tabela B, e se n existir colocar nulo na visualização da tabela em html?
Já tentei diversas alternativas inclusive, inner join.

Obrigada!

Comment: Quando você faz a busca a coluna qtd_tarefa vem como null quando não tem tarefa?

Comment: Não. Qd uso var_dump, aparece só os valores das tarefas que existem na tabela B.

Comment: coloquei uma exemplificação de como está aparecendo no html e como eu preciso q apareça.

Comment: Tenta colocar ao invés de vazio ="" coloque vazio="teste" pra ver como aparece.

Comment: Coloquei, mas não apareceu. Ele só mostra o que está na tabela B. E faz sentido porque meu ID da nova tarefa (tabela A) , não existe na tabela B. Mas não tô conseguindo enxergar como tratar isso.
Acho que qd chega no select como o id da tarefa da loja não existe ele nem continua.

Comment: Talvez um inner join da tabela A com a tabela B. Só vai retornar os registros que existam nas duas tabelas.

Comment: Sim, já tentei tb e não foi. Pq só pega o que existe em ambos, como você disse.

Comment: Vou tentar com left e right join p ver.

Comment: Também n funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Você disse que uma loja "pode" cadastrar 5 tarefas e depois mais uma. 
Então temos um maximo de 6 tarefas.
Essa sua tabela no html deve de conter 6 colunas de tarefas, tarefa1 a tarefa5 e a nova tarefa. 
Problema não está no sql, pois ele só recupera do banco oq realmente existe cadastrado, caso existir menos devemos criar as celulas vazias como você deseja, então
No seu loop:

```
while($table3 = $dados3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){


                 $qtd_tarefa = $table3->qtd_tarefa;

                    //só que as tarefas novas n tem dados antigos na minha tabela B, ele é inexistente, aí quebra a tabela
                     if($qtd_tarefa!=null){ //usei null mas n funcionou
                                    echo'<td>'.$qtd_tarefa.'</td>';
                              }else{
                                     $vazio="";
                                             echo'<td>'.$vazio.'</td>';
                                                }

                                                   }
```

Acrescente um condador de tarefas encontradas.
e ao final do loop recrie as celulas da tabela vazia, E mesmo que tenha cadastrado menos de 5 tarefas as colunas vazias serão criadas e sua tabela no html estará correta.
Conforme Exemplo:

```
$contadorTarefas = 0;
while($table3 = $dados3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  $contadorTarefas++;
  $qtd_tarefa = $table3->qtd_tarefa;
  echo'<td>'.$qtd_tarefa.'</td>';
}
//Se não existe tarefa para preencher todas as colunas de tarefas, cria as que faltam vazias
while ($contadorTarefas < 6) {
  $contadorTarefas++;
  echo'<td></td>';
}
```

Comment: Oi, Jonas. Então, a loja pode cadastrar qts quiser futuramente.. Não existe uma qtd máxima, mas vou testar sua ideia, acho que o contador pode ser a resposta.